# How to SIMPLY validate a very simple drop down in PHP, no need for arrays

Tags: php

I want to validate a drop down select on a form, I want the visitor to select one value, any value is ok. I can put values manually, so no need for anything complicated like arrays.

I can understand the validation for email and name, but how can I do this for a drop down select?

I put the form online over here:

http://satearn.com/question/landing_page.html

```
       <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
                            <div class="section">
                                <span>1</span>First &amp; Last Name</div>
                            <div class="inner-wrap testbruno">
                                <input type="text" name="first_last_name" class="form-style-10-input">
                            </div>
                            <div class="section">
                                <span>2</span>Email Address</div>
                            <div class="inner-wrap">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-style-10-input">
                            </div>
                            <div class="section">
                             <span>3</span>Budget</div>
                            <div class="inner-wrap">
                                <select name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down">
                                    <option value="$499">$499</option>
                                    <option value="$999">$999</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input name="Sign Up" type="submit" value="Send">

                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Under is the PHP page:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "bruno@xuzo.com";

    $email_subject = "My own subject Line Bruno";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['budget_selection'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_last_name = $_POST['first_last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $budget_selection = $_POST['budget_selection']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }




  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Customer First Name: ".clean_string($first_last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Customer Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Budget Selection: ".clean_string($budget_selection)."\n";







// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: You can add required parameter in select field. It will compulsion to select this drop down.

Comment: I did that, not working:  <select required name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down">

Comment: <select required></select> adding required at last parameter. or add required='required' at last.

Comment: I tried this:  <select  name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down" required>  not working either  and this:  <select name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down" required='required'>

Comment: add like this <select name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down" required='required' > <option value="">select</option>
                                    <option value="$499">$499</option>
                                    <option value="$999">$999</option>
                                </select>

Comment: yes, this is works ;) Can I do that for all the fields and ditch the php validation? Is this JS or HTML5? Is it safe, broswer supported?

Comment: it just client side browser validation you have to validate in server side aslo

Answer (score 0):

add like this

```
<select name="budget_selection" class="form-style-10-drop-down" required='required' > 
   <option value="">select</option> 
   <option value="$499">$499</option> 
   <option value="$999">$999</option> 
</select>
```

It just client side browser validation you have to validate in server side also.

Comment: How can I validate server side , with the PHP code above?